# HTML TAGS dont working when i have a PHP ECHO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have a `longtext` column in my database mysql.
This column have HTML tags. When I echo this with PHP, the tags dont work.

Here is my `echo`:
`<p><?php echo $data["news"][0]["cad_texto_noticia"]?></p>`

And here is the output:
`<p>O Minist&eacute;rio da Justi&ccedil;a (MJ) deve decidir, at&eacute; o fim de junho, se vai propor a redu&ccedil;&atilde;o de impostos sobre cigarros fabricados no Brasil. Em mar&ccedil;o, uma&nbsp;<a href="#">portaria assinada pelo ministro S&eacute;rgio Moro instituiu um grupo de trabalho</a></p>`

I need the output to not show special characters and tags work.

[image]

Comment: How do they "*not work*"? That seems to be perfectly valid HTML. The 'special characters' are called HTML entities, and will render the foreign characters correctly on your page. In fact, they're the *recommended* approach to do so.

Comment: Yes, but I need the tag not to be printed, but rather "interpreted"

Comment: show us your code?

Comment: Jeez... [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: @NodirRashidov What exactly do you need?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan ```html_entity_decode()``` worked to me. THANKS!

Comment: looks like your CMS\code is running  `htmlspecialchars()` before entering the data into the database. which going to be a problem if you want to allow raw HTML;

Comment: @tim Hmmm, yes! Im using FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to store HTML in your DB, you shouldn't sanitize it.

Comment: @Barmar Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `htmlspecialchars_decode`

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($data["news"][0]["cad_texto_noticia"];))?></p>
```